# Why does my while loop gets stuck ? -Programming in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that counts de caracteres between "a" "t" "g" and "t" "a" "g" or "t" "g" "a"or "t" "a" "a" inside of a vector. But my code gets stuck in the while loop. An example would be like x = "a" "a" "a" "t" "a" "t" "g" "t" "c" "g" "t " "t " "t" "t" "a" "g". In this example the code should count 6 characters between "a" "t" "g" and "t" "a" "g". Any help will be appreciated :) .

```
orfs<-function(x,p){
count<-0
cntorfs<-0
n<-length(x)
v<-n-2
for (i in 1:v){
if(x[i]=="a"&& x[i+1]=="t"&& x[i+2]=="g"){
  k<-i+3;
  w<-x[k]
  y<-x[k+1]
  z<-x[k+2]
  while (((w!="t")&&(y!="a")&& (z!="g"))||((w!="t")&&(y!="a")&&(z!="a"))||((w!="t")&&(y!="g")&& (z!="a"))||(i+2>v)){
    count<-count+1
    k<-k+1
    w<-x[k]
    y<-x[k+1] 
    z<-x[k+2]
  }
  }
if(count>p){
  cntorfs<-cntorfs+1 
} 
if (count!=0){
  count<-0
}
}
cat("orf:",cntorfs)
}
```

Comment: Welcome! What is the value for p passed to the function?  Please edit the provided code to show how you call your function.

Comment: if the number of caracters counted is smaller than p , it will not add to the cntorfs variável. That means the patern that was found is too smal to considerat.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* inefficient and un-R-like way to count the number of characters between two patterns.

Here is an alternative using `gsub` that should get you started and can be extended to account for the other stop codons:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "g", "t", "c", "g", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "g")

nchar(gsub("[actg]*atg([actg]*)tag[actg]*", "\\1", paste0(x, collapse = "")))
#[1] 6
```

A more robust and general approach can be found [here](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~kbessonov/archived_data/GBIO009-1course2012/presentations/HW1_2_review_slides_ORF_Finder.pdf) making use of `Biostrings::matchPattern`. I would strongly advise against reinventing the wheel here, and instead recommend using some of the standard Bioconductor packages that were developed for exactly these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thanks! I will try with the function gsub().